# Div Element is Spilling of the Page Horizontally While the parent element is not

Tags: html, css, width

I have a div on my that contains pieces of information on my webpage. I'm having a problem where when the window gets smaller,  part of the div gets cropped off the page.

Notes:
I have in my CSS inside my body element `overflow-x: hidden;`

The element that is spilling off the page contains a parent element. However, the parent element doesn't spill off the page.

View my code here
https://codepen.io/Tech-World/pen/ExLgNZq

Code added below:

```js
scrollTo (0, 800)
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: none;
}

.homepage-info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1100px;
    width: 100vw;


}

.why-heading {
    text-align: center;
}

.info-blocks {
    background-color: rgb(29, 31, 29);
    height: 100px;
    padding: 500px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.info-block {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    color: white;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
   padding: 30px;
   margin: 50px;
   border-radius: 10px;  
}




#affordable {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 500px;
    left: 1245px;
}

#real-code {
    position:absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 650px;
}

#in-person {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 500px;
    left: 40px;
}

#code-line-1 {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 825px;
    left: 43.5%;
}

#code-line-2 {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 800px;
    left: 35.5%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="homepage-info">
        <h1 class="why-heading">Scroll down and shrink your window size</h1>
        <div class="info-blocks">
        <div class="fade-out info-block right-align " id="affordable">
            <h2>Salve</h2>
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>

        <div class="fade-out info-block left-align" id="real-code">
            <h2>Hola</h2>
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>

        <div class="fade-out info-block right-align" id="in-person">
            <h2>Dobro</h2>
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post your code here

Comment: @Rohit Gupta I added my code to the question.

Comment: You are using absolute positioning, so of course it gets cropped off, that part has left:1245px.  At the moment it's a mess and impossible to figure out the nesting intent of the divs.  I would suggest that you start again, don't use absolutes, build it up from scratch.  Do a different background-color on each div so you can see. After each layer, resize and make sure it all works.

Comment: The browser will let you see the impact of resizing if you do a right click - Inspect

Answer (score 0):

Check below link for revised code.
https://codepen.io/nandujasthi/pen/zYjKzJz

Left of the div is mentioned in pixel with absolute position of element. Instead you can use the percentages to make it work efficiently in all the devices. Please check the link

```css
body {
  overflow-x: none;
}
.homepage-info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    width: 100vw;
    left: 0;
}

.why-heading {
    text-align: center;
}

.info-blocks {
    background-color: rgb(29, 31, 29);
    height: 100px;
    padding: 500px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.info-block {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    color: white;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
   padding: 30px;
   margin: 50px;
   border-radius: 10px;  
}
#affordable {
    position:absolute;
    top: 5%;
    right: 10%;
}

#real-code {
    position:absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 33%;
}

#in-person {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 500px;
    left: 10%;
}

#code-line-1 {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 825px;
    left: 43.5%;
}

#code-line-2 {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 800px;
    left: 35.5%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="homepage-info">
        <h1 class="why-heading">Scroll down and shrink your window size</h1>
        <div class="info-blocks">
        <div class="fade-out info-block right-align " id="affordable">
            <h2>Salve</h2>
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>

        <div class="fade-out info-block left-align" id="real-code">
            <h2>Hola</h2>
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>

        <div class="fade-out info-block right-align" id="in-person">
            <h2>Dobro</h2>
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </div>



        
    </div>
```

Comment: The div element ```info-blocks``` is still spilling of the page

Comment: Padding 500px might cause that issue ... can you make it in % instead of px. If that is not solving the issue please share the desired output design and give me the code in codepen link. So that I can help with accurate solution as per design

Comment: https://codepen.io/nandujasthi/pen/zYjKzJz - Please refer this updated link.  HTML and CSS are modified again